# Setting default function values for particular option values

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, options

I have a function with some optional arguments. How do I assign a value for the function when one of the optional arguments takes a particular value, regardless of any other argument values?

Comment: A clumsy way of doing it is to have a "public" function with optional arguments, whose sole purpose is to forward these arguments to a "private" function (maybe after some sanity checks). The private function can then use multiple dispatch to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant in the comment above:

First, the private version of the function, with no optional arguments (all arguments must be present): [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) can be used for specific argument values, for example

```
Fprivate[0] = "zero";
Fprivate[1] = "one";
Fprivate[x_] := ToString[x];
```

Second, the public version of the function, with optional arguments: it only forwards the arguments to the private function, using a [delayed assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html),

```
F[x_: 0] := Fprivate[x]
```

Try it out:

```
F[]          (*    "zero"    *)
F[0]         (*    "zero"    *)
F[1]         (*    "one"     *)
F[2]         (*    "2"       *)
```